# Combining an <a> tag and a <label>

Tags: html

I can't make a  and an  tag combine on HTML.
I'm trying to have text that when you click on it both click a checkbox and also lead you somewhere on the page i've tried to make it like that:

```
<a href"#somewhere"><label for"somecheckbox">Some Text</label></a>
```

But only the label worked, then I tried it like that:

```
<label for"somecheckbox"><a href"#somewhere">Some Text</a></label>
```

But then only the link works, is there any way in which we can use both?

Comment: Just do the checkbox with label and use javascript to do whatever else you need to do. But if your checkbox is leading the user to a section of the page then you probably should not use a checkbox

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are trying to nest [interactive content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#interactive_content). This is something you can't do via the W3C spec. See the [a tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a), for instance with it's permitted content.

You will need to use javascript to achieve what you want to do.

Here is a quick example:

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll("[data-for]");

//Set Event Handler
for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].addEventListener("click", function(event){
    //Get the target cb from the data attribute
    var cbTarget = this.dataset.for;
    //Check the cb
    document.getElementById(cbTarget).checked = true;
  });
}
```

```css
.head {margin-bottom: 100vh;}
```

```html
<div class="head">
<a href="#aTarget" data-for="aCheckBox">Click Me</a> <input type="checkbox" id="aCheckBox" />
</div>
<div id="aTarget">A Target</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do both navigation and toggle checkbox using tags, please use javascript to focus on target when checkbox is checked.

```
document.getElementById("somecheckbox").addEventListener("change", function(e){
  // see if it is checked
  if(e.target.checked){
    // and focus to specific id
    document.getElementById("somewhere").focus();
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the label, both the check box is checked and it goes to a location.

```js
const label = document.querySelector('[for=checkbox]');
const checkBox = document.querySelector('[name=checkbox]');
label.addEventListener('click', function (){
  checkBox.setAttribute("checked", "true");
  location.href = "#location";  
});
```

```css
#location {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -100px;
}
```

```html
<label for="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"/>
Check
</label>

<p id="location"> Some location </p>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
function Redirect(){
 if (document.getElementById('vehicle3').checked) 
  {
      window.location = "https://www.tutorialspoint.com";
  }
 }
</script>
<h1>Show checkboxes:</h1>

  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle1" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle2" value="Car"> I have a car<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle3" id='vehicle3' value="Boat" onClick='Redirect();'> I have a boat<br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</body>
</html>
```

This solution is what everyone suggesting using JavaScript your problem can be solved easily. As soon as you click on the 3rd checkbox it redirects you to a new webpage